# SQL alternative for fetching latest record of each item in a table using partition

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partition, rowcount

Im have been query the database to collectively fetch latest record or each item using PARTITION and ROW_COUNT() which works on MariaDB version 10.4* but i want to query the same on a MySQL version 5.7* database but it doesn't work there. I would like to figure out the alternative that will work on the MySQL database. Kindly help me out.
The query is as follows.

```
SELECT A_id, B_id, Created_at
FROM
(
   SELECT a.id as A_id, b.id as B_id, b.Created_at,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.Created_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM beta b 
   JOIN alpha a ON b.a_id = a.id 
) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a join to subquery which finds the latest record for each `id`:

```sql
SELECT a.id AS A_id, b.id AS B_id, b.Created_at
FROM alpha a
INNER JOIN beta b
    ON a.id = b.a_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id AS max_id, MAX(b.Created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM alpha a
    INNER JOIN beta b ON a.id = b.a_id
    GROUP BY a.id
) t
    ON t.max_id = a.id AND t.max_created_at = b.Created_at;
```

The idea here is that the additional join to the subquery above aliased as `t` will only retain the record, for each `a.id`, having the *latest* `Created_at` value from the B table.  This has the same effect as your current approach using `ROW_NUMBER`, without actually needing to use analytic functions.

Comment: i have done that but then i get this error "Unknown column 't.id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: @Mariwa You were right.  Try the updated version, it should work now.